# Missing Hadoop installation in Windows

Tags: windows, hadoop, hive, installation, hadoop2

I have installed Hadoop 2.x and its running fine in Windows 8.

```
 G:\hadoop\hive2.1\bin>jps
 10916 NameNode
 1588 DataNode
 3332 Jps
 4200 ResourceManager
 2444 NodeManager
```

And I have installed Hive also in Windows, But when I start Hive it's throwing an error saying:

```
  G:\hadoop\hive2.1\bin>hive
 "Missing hadoop installation: G:\hadoop\winutils must be set"
```

`HADOOP_HOME` is already set to `G:\hadoop\winutils` in `env` variables.

Please help here.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrongly set HADOOP_HOME.

Try below..

In User variables, configure HADOOP_HOME with following value.

HADOOP_HOME-->D:\Hadoop-2.8.1
In System variables, add following value in addition of existing path value.

path-->;D:\Hadoop-2.8.1\bin;
If you not ok with that above configurations just try below way.

Open cmd prompt, Just set home by setting path and home.

C:>set HADOOP_HOME=D:\Hadoop-2.8.1

C:>set PATH=%PATH%;%HADOOP_HOME%\bin
Now start hadoop services from same cmd prompt and then go to hive shell.

Hope this helpful for you.